# SQL Server : CASE statement in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server, how do I use a `CASE` statement within a `where` clause in a SQL statement?

I want to rewrite this query:

```
select * 
from Persons P
where P.Age = 20
  and P.FamilyName in (select Name
                       from AnotherTable)
```

Using a `case` statement. I want it so the second condition

```
(P.FamilyName in ....)
```

is executed only if `CheckFamilyName` is true.

Something like this:

```
select * 
from Persons P
where P.Age = 20
case when CheckFamilyName= true 
 then
    and P.FamilyName in (
              select Name
              From AnotherTable)
 else 
end
```

How do `case` statements in SQL work?

Comment: First thing : `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (like `a+b`) - **NOT** a statement. `CASE` can return a single, atomic value - it **cannot** be used to conditionally execute code fragments or code paths.

Answer (score 4):

```
where   P.Age = 20
        and 
        (
            not CheckFamilyName
            or
            P.FamilyName in (select Name From AnotherTable)
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

approach 1

```
select * 
from Persons P
where 1=1
    and P.Age = 20
    and (
        CheckFamilyName = 0
        or P.FamilyName in (select Name From AnotherTable)
    )
```

approach 2

```
select * 
from Persons P
where 1=1
    and P.Age = 20
    and CheckFamilyName = '0'
union all
select * 
from Persons P
where 1=1
    and P.Age = 20
    and CheckFamilyName = '1'
    and P.FamilyName in (select Name From AnotherTable)
```

Comment: If `CheckFamilyName` is `false`, this would still check family name?

Comment: Why do you add the `1=1` in both approaches?

Comment: it's a syntactic sugar, does not cost any processing power, and can be easily commented out.

Comment: Based on this [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) I don't see how it makes anything easier to read or express.  Merely adds unnecessary keystrokes.

Comment: as i mentioned before, it makes commenting out easier. based on OP question, if you comment out `--P.Age = 20` ( in `where P.Age = 20` ), then you have to go one line down and comment out the 'and' too. in my case you don't have to.

Comment: ... it's about how you like to draw on your canvas :)

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff - it is just one of those dumb things people do to make copy and paste easier -- like putting commas at the start of the line.  This way every line you would copy and paste is always the "same".  I've never seen it be much help and countless times it has introduced bugs.  This is not "syntatic sugar" it is coding style IMO and  a silly one at that.

Comment: thank you for your opinion, but it's only your opinion. you see my opinion is a little different. also there are almost 7.000.000.000 different opinions. you have a better idea helping the OP then do it :)

Comment: Historically 1=1 was used for places where the SQL parser demands a logical statement; for example, a `join` requires something after `on`, so 1=1 allows you to do a full join.  However, given that this is a beginner question I think 1=1 in the where clause will confuse SQL learners.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can (and probably should) use a join for your first case like this:

```
select * 
from Persons P
join anothertable A on A.Name = P.FamilyName
where P.Age = 20
```

It should be noted that this select statement will ONLY give you results with that family name.

So when you add in your new condition

```
select * 
from Persons P
join anothertable A on A.Name = P.FamilyName and P.CheckFamilyName= true 
where P.Age = 20
```

You will only get results where CheckFamilyName is true.

So we make it a left join.

```
select * 
from Persons P
left join anothertable A on A.Name = P.FamilyName and CheckFamilyName= true 
where P.Age = 20
```

This will include rows where checkfamilyname is true but name does not exist -- to validate those you can do the following

```
select * 
from Persons P
left join anothertable A on A.Name = P.FamilyName and CheckFamilyName= true 
where P.Age = 20 and (checkfamilyname = A.Name is not null)
```